# why is the placement of the table wrong?

Tags: tables, floats

I'm new Latex, I want to use make a table, and it works fine. the problem that I have is the position  of table in the document :

```
\chapter{chapter description }
\section{section name }
\subsetion{subsection}
here should the text be displayed 
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.3\textwidth}|c|c|c}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table Name   \label{tab:table_label}}
\end{table}
```

the pdf result hasn't the right order,
 I get  first  the table  and that the \chapter and section , subsection 
I don't what I'm doing wrong 
 any idea ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `table` is a floating environment, i.e. LaTeX will place the table at a place where it's 'best'

Comment: The MWE is not compilable (subseCtion) and not complete. When adding `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{tabularx}` I get the table at the end. Please be more precise with your question. Most questions on this topic will be answered here, I guess: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017

Comment: @Mico and the other s the quesiton how can I put the table in the document as wrote it the code

Comment: @Engine - If you don't want the tabular material to "float", don't place it in an environment such as `table` that is *meant to float*. Have a look at the link provided in Paul Gessler's comment for an in-depth explanation of how LaTeX's floating-object algorithm works. By the way, the example you provided contains two syntax errors and is hence not compilable as is. It's thus also not possible to deduce from your example exactly *where* the tabular material should be located.